# How do I check if an ElggGroup exists using the name?

Tags: php, elgg

I just want something similar to the function [`get_user_by_username`](http://reference.elgg.org/1.8/users_8php.html#a9b2b85c41543e5793de404b4d2a5bcf6) for groups.

Some hints:
The name of the group is a builtin attribute of groups accessible through `group->name`. It looks like the metadata functions don't work for builtin attributes.

I'm using Elgg 1.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with [this function](https://github.com/jdnavarro/Elgg/commit/930145641418b8b452617a00c09b1ffbddcbe186). I included it [in a pull request](https://github.com/Elgg/Elgg/pull/109#issuecomment-3128983) to Elgg.

See also [Cash' comment](https://github.com/Elgg/Elgg/pull/109#commitcomment-791229) suggesting to use `elgg_get_entities` to do the same thing more easily.